# Excel - Compare the value of two fields and change color depending on results

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to compare two fields in an Excel Spreadsheet and if a number is higher then change the background of that cell and if it is lower change it also. For a further explanation I have created something below to kind of explain (not a VBA guru so I know formatting not correct).

```
If J11 > L11 then
  L11 background = green
Elseif
  J11 < L11 then
  L11 background = red
endif
```

Was wondering what would be the easiest way to complete this on all the rows in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Easiest way would be `Conditional Formatting`. You would need 2 conditions, one for when the value is higher and the other for when it is lower

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional Formatting for this (Home > Conditional Formatting). Under 'New Rule...' select 'Use Formula to determine...' and put in your formula there. You can to write 2 rules - 1 for the > comparison and another for the <

Comment: Conditional formatting is absolutely the right way to go! Until you have 147 conditional formats to apply, then it's just a nightmare...